# AutoHotKey, pick a random word from an array from a text file in a folder

Tags: arrays, random, autohotkey

I need help writing an application.

I have different arrays in text files and I would like one word to be randomly selected from them.

animals.txt

For example
[
‘cat’,
‘dog’,
‘horse’
]

and

furits.txt

[
'apple',
'banana,
]

When I press: ctrl + a

And the same for fruit

When I press: ctrl + x

Is it possible?

or

When I press: ctrl + d

output:

random animal + 'some text' + random fruit

Unfortunately, I don't have much time to try it, so I'm counting on your help